# Цикл for в джаве, непонятен вывод при двух циклах for

Tags: java, циклы

Добрый день! Задача вывести 1.)десять восьмерок по горизонтали и 2.)десять восьмерок по вертикали, не учитывая те что по горизонтали.

Данный код выводит 10 цифр по горизонтали, и 8 цифр по вертикали. Хотя цикл составлен идентично. Не могу понять, что я не усмотрел? Спасибо.

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int j = 8;
        System.out.print(j);//напишите тут ваш код
    }
    for (int l = 1; l <10; l++)
    {
        int k = 8;
        System.out.println(k);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Я не сразу понял ваш вопрос, но потом подправил свой ответ.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Различие кроется в предложениях

```
System.out.print(j);//напишите тут ваш код
```

и

```
System.out.println(k);
```

В втором предложении вывода добавляется символ новой строки. То есть выводится строка и происходит переход на новую строку.

В первом предложении перевода на новую строку нет. Текущая позиция консоли устанавливается в месте окончания вывода значения.

Имейте в виду, что данные циклы

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

и

```
for (int l = 1; l <10; l++)
```

повторяются не 10 раз, а всего лишь 9 раз.

В результате вы получаете, что первый цикл вывел 9 восьмерок. Так как перевода на новую строку после этого цикла не было, то в следующем цикле в первой итерации новая восьмерка выводится в той же самой строке, что и предыдущие восьмерки. Тем самым вы получаете в итоге 10 восьмерок на одной строке. А по вертикале на одну восьмерку из 9 выводимых меньше.

Вам следовало написать либо

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

либо

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

И между циклами еще вставить предложение с пустым выводом для перехода на новую строку.

```
System.out.println("");
```

Либо вы могли бы сделать так, что в первом цикле выводится 9 восьмерок, как у вас было раньше, а во втором цикле уже выводить 11 восьмерок

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)

//...

for (int l = 1; l <= 11; l++)
```

Comment: Что-то не понимаю.  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) - выводит 10 раз восьмерку. А как можно это наглядно посмотреть, чтобы понять про позицию консоли? Или можно объяснить, что происходит во время выполнения одного из циклов когда не выводится значение восьмерки?

Comment: а понял, то есть сначала выводится восьмерка, а потом только происходит переход на следующую строку. =)

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov Данное предложение for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)  выводит только 9 восьмерок по горизонтали.. А в следующем цикле в его первой итерации очередная восьмерка выводится в этой же строке. После чего делается перевод строки, и в итоге вы получаете всего 8 восьмерок по вертикале.

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov Да, все правильно. Это делается при первой итерации во втором цикле. Его первый вывод происходит на той же строке, что и в предыдущем цикле.